# How to retain the ActionBar's SearchView when navigating to another fragment?

Tags: android, searchview

My RecyclerView can be filtered via a SearchView in the fragment's ActionBar:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_tasks, menu)

    val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
    val searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            viewModel.setSearchQuery(newText.orEmpty())
            return true
        }
    })
}
```

The problem is, that when the user now navigates to another fragment, this SearchView is collapsed which seems to send an empty string to `onQueryTextChange`. Here is an image of the stack trace when it happens:

[image]

This clears the filter in my ViewModel and when the user navigates back to the RecyclerView fragment, all unfiltered items are shown again.

I could store the search query manually in `onDestroyView`, and then restore it in `onCreateOptionsMenu` but then the RecyclerView will have a visible animation from the full list to the filtered list, which is very confusing. Instead, the RecyclerView should just keep its state when navigating back.

**Is there a way to have the SearchView not send an empty string when it is collapsed?**